# How to programatically find Target SDK version for UWP (Windows 10) apps

Tags: c++, windows, uwp

Is there a way that I can programmatically find the Target SDK version that my UWP appx was built with (preferably with C++ or C#)?  I assumed that there would be a macro of some sort to give me this information, but apparently not.  AFAIK, there was an API called `GetSDKReferenceFiles::TargetSDKVersion` that would give this information to you, but it appears to be a Windows 8.x feature only.  This is quite surprising, and I've been searching for quite some time now.

Why am I asking for this functionality?  Because I discovered that some UWP features for Windows 10 actually give different results for some target versions.  My laptop runs 10.0.10586 and my Surface Pro runs 10.0.15603, and I share code between the two (I can't upgrade the former because it's for work; long story) plus I want my game to work properly on other versions of Win10 and not limit it to certain runtimes if I can avoid it (but if I have to I will).  So is there a way to programmatically determine what version your app is targeted at?  Thanks.

Comment: It is impossible to change the target version at run-time. And it makes no sense. Please detail why you need this function, if you do have some issues you should have other ways to resolve. For " discovered that some UWP features for Windows 10 actually give different results for some target versions.", are you sure this is caused by different app target version, not the OS version? Can you for example which feature?

Comment: Well, to be honest, I'm not requesting to change the target version at runtime.  That isn't what I was asking.  I was hoping to find out if there was an API or a Macro that tells you what your target API version is.  But upon further inspection of my code, your alternative is actually the reason why.  I instead added code that gets the OS version, and that solved my problem.

Comment: But to provide an example, my code used to get the desktop resolution is what I was dealing with.  GetWidth/HeightInPixels works for latter 15063, but VisibleBounds*RawPixelsPerViewPixel worked for 10586, but just gets the window dimensions for the former.